# ADFS Claim Rule - Using ObjectClass

Tags: active-directory, ldap, adfs

I am attempting to create a custom claim rule in ADFS but I am at a loss as to how to do it.  I have the following for users in my AD:

```
ObjectClass = PrivatePerson
Attribute = PrivatePersonAttribute1
```

I need to be able to return the value for the attribute in the claim as NameID.  Anyone have any suggestions, I am at a complete loss here?